# There are infinitely many projections

Tags: multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

[image]

Can anyone explain please why such projections are infinitely many?

Comment: Can you find infinitely many projections from $\mathbb R^2$ onto the $x$-axis?

Comment: There is basically only one _orthogonal_ projection (if that makes sense in $X$), but there are infinitely many other projections.

Comment: A hint for the construction: if $x,y$ are two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V$ has them as columns in that order, then $V \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} V^{-1}$ is a projection onto the span of $x$. Now notice that this matrix depends on $y$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I tried but any results! Only projection that I know it's: $P(x,y)=(x,0)$

Comment: Well, I suggest you pick a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, and write down the equations that say that it is a projection onto the $x$-axis.

Comment: @RFZ That's an orthogonal projection. But there are others: if you take a point off the axis and draw any non-horizontal line, it will intersect the $x$ axis. The point where it intersects is the image of a projection.

Comment: @Ian, I took such operator $P(x,y)=(x/2,0)$ but it doesn't work

Comment: @RFZ That indeed doesn't work, but that's not what you get if you draw a line as I suggested. What's the equation of the line with slope $m \neq 0$ passing through $(x,y)$, where $y \neq 0$? Where is its $x$-intercept? If you call this $x$-intercept $L(x,y)$ (where $m$ we hold $m$ constant) then $P(x,y)=(L(x,y),0)$ is a projection.

Comment: @Ian, Sorry for my English! But what does mean " if you take a point off the axis"? It means that i must take point on $x$-axis?

Comment: @RFZ "Off the axis" in this context meant "off the $x$-axis", meaning a point $(x,y)$ with $y \neq 0$.

Comment: @Ian, Thank you! I understand. But how to generalize it to my above example?

Comment: A linear map is defined by its action on a basis of the domain. For a projection the domain and codomain are the same; for simplicity let's say it's $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now you're projecting onto a subspace of dimension $0<k<n$. Then you need to map $n-k$ basis vectors to $0$ and $k$ of them to linearly independent elements of the range. For convenience's sake, let us choose $k$ of our basis vectors to be in the subspace. Then they will be mapped to themselves. Choosing the other $n-k$ basis vectors differently will change the resulting linear map.

Comment: One way to write this out rigorously is to choose basis vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n$,$V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \dots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$, and $D=\begin{bmatrix} I_{k \times k} & 0_{k \times (n-k)} \\ 0_{(n-k) \times k} & 0_{(n-k) \times (n-k)} \end{bmatrix}$. Then $V D V^{-1}$ is your projection. What I have done here is basically diagonalization in reverse.